# Android Studio editor dont see databinding references after update to 3.5

Tags: android, android-studio

I've recently updated my Android Studio to 3.5, but I've discovered, that in this version Android Studio can't see databinding references (BR.databinding) and turns them red, but code is working. How to fix this editor error? I already tried invalidation and restart

[image]

Comment: Did you try a `./gradlew clean` too? There seems to be an issue and some people downgraded to 3.4 in the mean time, check [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139826945) or just a [databinding search](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=%22Android%20Studio%22%203.5%20databinding)

Comment: Try with change params name

Comment: I had a similar problem but with BR generated ids from XML variables not from Bindable annotations there was no red color IDE detected error but when I build the project an error with cannot generate BR would appear so I changed the XML variable name to a Unique BR name then removed any usage of it then built the project so it built successfully then I used the BR id and now it works perfectly so try the **unique naming** maybe it 'll work.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes cached data doesn't get updated. That means that your project is using old resources. What you should do is go to your menu:

```
File --> |Invalidate Caches / Restart|
```

Or if that doesn't work you can go and follow this process:

1. Clean your project. This cleans indexes.
2. Re-build your project. That's basically syncing with the new indexes.
3. Run the project and see if it works.

Comment: I think you missed the part where the OP wrote: `I already tried invalidation and restart`

Comment: Oh yeah, I missed that. Well, maybe cleaning the project will work.

Answer (score 0):

Approaches that don't help me:

- Clean your project
- Re-build your project
- File -> Invalidate Caches | Restart
- Removing .idea directory
- Running from terminal `./gradlew clean cleanBuildCache`

For my case it started to work after I moved `.idea` dir to another folder, restarted Android Studio, it generated again `.idea` dir, then I replaced new generated `.idea` with old one and restarted Android Studio.

I posted a bug about that: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153109791